# Automated database versioning and Mercurial (and probably git)

Tags: mercurial, teamcity, dvcs

We've been using subversion for years, but are now moving to mercurial.

We have a nifty automated database versioning system using teamcity and a script. (It's .net and msbuild and powershell, but that's irrelevant). ]

We have a database directory as such:

```
/database/
/database/functions
/database/migration
/database/storedprocedures
/database/views
```

the `migration` folder contains things DDL and data modifications.

The source / build system works like so:

1. Developer makes a change to a stored procedure
2. Developer commits change to svn
3. Teamcity checks out code and builds
4. Database Migration Generation Script runs that gets the svn revision that kicked off the  build
5. Script does a diff in the database directory between the last known revision and this revision. For all files that are in the diff, it concatenates them into a file with filename %buildnumber%_%revision%.sql
6. Script puts a final 'update databaseinfo setversion = '%buildnumber%' into fiel
7. Script then commits this new file back into subversion
8. build is packaged

Then at release time, or dev time, it's matter of running the SQL migration files in order and voila, database is upgraded and migrated.

It's good system, because it means you do your work and don't have to worry about writing migrations, or noting your changes, no "sorry about the test environment, I forgot to write the migration for that stored procedure, wait 30 minutes and I'll give you a new build"

However, with the move to mercurial, step `7. Script then commits this new file back into subversion` doesn't work well.

With subversion it's not a big deal because you're just committing back to a database directory that never gets modified outside the build system.

With mercurial (and I'm a bit of a newbie here), we need to commit and push the change which entails doing a pull and update. I can get this to work no problem, but it comes at the cost of putting the source in an invalid state and it just feels as though it's the wrong thing to do.

I'm thinking of utilising the commit / pre commit hooks inside mercurial, but then we lose the the build number versioning and buy ourselves a problem in finding a naming convention to version the database on that works and then works again when we have a branch.

I'm wondering what other people do around this?

Comment: Have you considered using liquibase? Or any other solutions like dbdeploy, that imply you storing the *changes* rather than the most actual state.

Comment: liquibase et al work on defining the changes for you database. This is fine from a schema point of view because you need to define them at some point, but the issue with them is that if I modify a stored procedure and work with it locally, I then have to write a migration for that stored procedure and this is something that I (and every dev I've ever worked) with continually forget to do and it's very easy to get into a situation where your source doesn't match what's in production.

Comment: "I can get this to work no problem, but it comes at the cost of putting the source in an invalid state" - please elaborate, I **can't see any difference** with SVN-workflow (where additional commit means additional `svn up` on developers WCses also)

Comment: And... with Liquibase - liquibase just create migration script instead of your hand-made tool. just use it the same way, as your current system (in hook, without human intervention). But it's mostly irrelevant, BTW, because I still can't see your troubles with Mercurial backend for now

Comment: Lazy badger, thanks for the comments, but the difference is that with the svn workflow, you can "push" a new revision of a file without having to update the current source tree. (in a build env, you don't want to build x, then update to (x+1) mid build. 

(And  The problem that is that liquibase when I modifiy a stored procedure, I then need to do the additional step of informing liquibase about it. (I checked the docs and there is an auto generation layer for liquibase, but doesn't include stored procedures)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For what it's worth. I ended up doing this with a mercurial commit hook.

Since we're using windows & powershell.

I put this in the hgrc

```
[hooks]
commit.MigrateDatabase=powershell -File ".\BuildAndDeploy\DatabaseMigration_HgHook.ps1"
```

And the in the powershell file, to cut along story short

$hg_node = (gci -Path env:hg_node).Value
$hgCommandLine = "hg status --change $hg_node  > .\Migration.Working\ModifiedFiles.txt"
Invoke-Expression $hgCommandLIne

Then parsed the ModifiedFiles.txt for any added or modified files, concatenated them into another file and versioned this based on a combination of the the version and the date it was comitted.

Answer (score 2):

If your automated change is this:

1. Pull and update
2. Create a new file in a directory
3. Commit that new file into the repository
4. Push

Then what you risk doing is timing-wise that you get an extra head. In the time from you pulled, someone else might have pushed a new head (on top of the old one), that your local repository (on the build server) doesn't know about.

This is all that is going to be wrong. If you're not modifying existing files, then there is not going to be a merge conflict here, and since you're just committing on top of an existing changeset the build server is not going to merge at all.

ie. timing-wise, this is what will happen. This is the current main repository timeline:

```
1---2---3---4---5
```

You pull, and get this to your build server. Then you create a new file with the changes, and commit, forming this timeline:

```
1---2---3---4---5---6
```

In the meantime, another developer has also pushed a new changeset to the main repository, so when you push, you get this:

```
1---2---3---4---5---6
                 \
                  \-7
```

(6 or 7 is your new changeset, the other is from the other developer).

This is the worst that can happen. You *can* try to automerge on the build server. Again, this should not produce a merge conflict.

Comment: You'll have to forgive my hg-newbieness, but this is what we were doing, pushing a new head. The problem as you've written is when we do a build at t1, at t2 a developer checks in. At t3 the migration file is created and we push a new head.

the thing is that we want all devs to be working off the tip, so that leaves us with merging. Considering the build is kicked off at t1, if at t3 we updated to include t2 so we could push back. It just feels icky. 

I guess my question should be phrased. "This is how we do migration workflow in svn. I know I can't do the same workflow. What do others do?"